# Trying to learn on how to graph a circle.

Tags: graphing-functions

If possible, can someone explain or teach me how to graph a circle with these given center and radius?

- center A (-2,7) radius;4
- center A (-8,-5) radius;3
- center A (√5, 2√2) radius √10

My teacher in 10th grade didnt taught us how. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_%28drawing_tool%29

Answer (score 2):

This is the idea: get a ruler and [compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_(drawing_tool)). Draw a coordinate system and with the aid of the ruler mark the location of the center $A$. Now, open the compass along the ruler until it reaches the length of the desired radius$^{1}$, place the pointy end of the compass on top the previously marked center and just draw the circle with the other one.

---

$^{1}$ This method with the ruler works out perfectly fine until you find a length that is not a rational number. For that you use Pythagoras' theorem to find the length.

> ***EXAMPLE:*** Draw a circle of radius $1$ with center $(-1, -\sqrt{2})$

[image]

> **Step 1:** Draw a coordinate system

Use the ruler for this one

> **Step 2:** Mark the center of the circle

Here the center requires the length $\sqrt{2}$, remember that $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2}$, therefore, if we draw a triangle of sides $|\overline{AB}| = 1$ and $|\overline{BC}| = 1$, the hypotenuse will measure $|\overline{AC}| = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2}$ which is the desired length. So stretch the compass to measure the side $\overline{AC}$ and mark the center of the circle with this number

> **Step 3:** Select the radius and draw the circle

For this last step the radius is just $1$, so we can use the ruler again